# Class extended to BigDecimal returns object from superclass type

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to do some calculations with money. In order to prevent rounding errors I decided to use BigDecimal instead of double or float. Now I think, this wasn't a good idea, because it makes calculations extremly difficult.

I created a class named Euro that extends from BigDecimal in order to override the toString and equals methods.

Now, if I want to add a number to an Euro object, I would do it like

```
Euro sum = (new Euro(10)).add(new Euro(15));
```

The problem here is that add(...) returns an object from class BigDecimal which I can not cast to Euro, so I added this to the Euro class:

```
public Euro add(Euro euro){
    return new Euro(euro.add((BigDecimal) this).floatValue());
}
```

What can I do now, instead of rewriting all methods from BigDecimal in Euro? I guess, the best solution is to use an integer for cents instead of BigDecimal, because than I can write

```
int sumCents = 1000 + 1500;
```

instead of the long term above.

Comment: Don't extend BigDecimal. It's not supposed to be extended. It should actually be final and it's not only because they forgot to make it final on the first release, and kept it that way to stay backward compatible. If you want to create a Euro class, make it **use** (i.e. wrap) a BigDecimal. Not extend it. Not sure why you don't just use BiDecimal directly though, and why you transform the result to a float value, since you precisely wanted to avoid using floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to favor composition over inheritance in this case.  When you're subclassing `BigDecimal` to make `Euro`, you are saying that a `Euro` *is* a `BigDecimal`.  It would be more accurate to say that an amount of `Money` *has* a `BigDecimal` (or in general, an amount).  It also has a symbol, here a Euro.

You could also use a different implementation, e.g. number of cents as you already have thought of, to store the amount as an integer.  This is a clue that inheriting from `BigDecimal` isn't correct.  Also, it doesn't make sense to call `pow` on a `Euro`, even though it makes sense on a `BigDecimal`.  A `Euro` is not a `BigDecimal`.

Besides, calling `floatValue` (or `doubleValue`) just to convert to `Euro` would have defeated the point of using `BigDecimal` in the first place - to avoid floating-point round-off errors when representing an amount of money.

When you use composition, then you can expose only the methods you want, e.g. `add` and `subtract`, without overriding methods and creating new subclass objects during each mathematical operation.  The mathematical operations are done on an instance variable, not on the class as a whole, as an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to choose the Integer for cents solution.

Comment: @PhilippNiedergesäß: If you use cents, you can't calculate, say, percentages or annuities accurately.